# Request.IsAuthenticated false when using MYSQL database : MVC5

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using asp.net identity framework with MYSQL database. 
After following few articles i was successfully able to add user in database.
However, when i try to login user successfully login but 
Request.IsAuthenticated is always false.

User registered Successfully in MYSQL database :

[image]

Trying to login user . User logged in successful and redirects to home page but username not showing on home. It is because Request.IsAuthenticated is false.

[image]

I have tried change authenication mode in web.config but it is not working. 
PS : when i use MYSQL Server everything works fine.

Any help shall be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The method IsAuthenticated always returns false when it's called in the same request as the user has been authenticated.

The problem isn't your MySql database, the problem is the FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie() - see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx).

If you're using the bootstraped asp.net mvc project, the user is redirected to the home using RedirectToAction("Index", "Home") that causes a new request to be fired and so the IsAuthenticated should work. Did you change something in the redirection or in the partial view _LoginPartial.cshtml?